# Gallery images stored elsewhere (preferably Google Drive)

Tags: images, gallery

I host client galleries on my website using the standard WP gallery but the disk space costs a lot this way.

I was wondering if there's a way to show pictures in a gallery that are loaded from another source?

In an ideal situation I would like to load the images from a folder on Google drive as this is where they are already stored (seems a shame to have to upload them again to somewhere).

Just to clarify I'm not looking to upload to WP from drive but to only store them on drive.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this wordpress plugin for a while now.
http://codecanyon.net/item/useyourdrive-google-drive-plugin-for-wordpress/6219776

I have done alot of searching to try and find a perfect solution to having a large free Storage place for images and then showing those images from my website. This was the only solution i could find for showing the images on a google drive storage.
( and I searched alot ). Google Drv is fine for files PDF,s Vids etc, but it still cant handle images well when they are embedded on a personal website.

Scott

Comment: Please state your affiliation with the plug-in, especially because it is commercial. Additionally it is recommended to add an explanation on *how to use* the plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I was wanting to do the same as the OP. I have a self-hosted WordPress site where I wanted to display clients' proof images in a post, but I didn't want to host them on our server.

I've just opened a Zenfolio account, and it's going to cost me $85 AUD a year for their basic package, but that is fine.

The great thing for me is that by using the [ZenfolioPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/zenfoliopress/installation/), I can basically slot a Zenfolio gallery in just using a shortcode.

I'm literally just changing things over right now, but it seems to be working perfectly so far.

I have no affiliation with either Zenfolio, or the plugin developer - I am an end user just looking for an easy way to have the images displayed on my site, but be hosted elsewhere. Just putting it out there in case it helps someone else out.

Comment: This plug in was last updated 6 years ago